# Update HTML form with Javascript while typing

Tags: javascript, html

I can update an HTML form using Javascript, when the user hits enter when on something on the form or when he triggers the `onclick` event on the "submit" button, but I want the form to be updated while the user is typing something.

I know that I can do `Infinity loop`, yet it is not a good idea; or I can check after intervals but it will cause unnecessary checking, which I don't want.

Comment: you can use `onchange` handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `keyUp` event handler with the input field contained within your form.

References: [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp), 
                [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

[UPDATE]

You missed round brackets at function definition, check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sohelkhalifa/tQcWf/3/)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and based on [this post](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml) and [sohel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14849240/918015) I managed to get it working. Now I would like to share my solution in form of a short working example: If you type your name in the first field it will suggest an email address in the second one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script> 
function nameModify(emailElement, nameElement) {

        emailElement.value = nameElement.value + '@stackoverflow.com';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="aform" action="#"> 
        <input type="text" name="name" onkeyup="nameModify(this.form.elements['email'], this);" >
        <input type="text" name="email" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: actually not! I want to update other fields. please read my last edit.